# How can I use Monte Carlo to find a monthly premium?

Tags: monte-carlo, markov-process

The credit swap is as follows: I own a 100 million bond with an A rating. If that bond rating drops to a new low (during the ten years), I receive 20 million. I pay \$x a month for the arrangement.

The probabilities are as follows:

```c
p[1][1] = 0.9725; p[1][2] = 0.0275;                   // AAA to AAA, AAA to AA. 
p[2][1] = 0.0020; p[2][2] = 0.9742; p[2][3] = 0.0238; // AA to AAA;  AA to AA;   AA to A;
p[3][2] = 0.0020; p[3][3] = 0.9825; p[3][4] = 0.0155; // A to AA;    A to A;     A to BBB;
p[4][3] = 0.0073; p[4][4] = 0.9819; p[4][5] = 0.0108; // BBB to A;   BBB to BBB; BBB to BB;
p[5][4] = 0.0030; p[5][5] = 0.9783; p[5][6] = 0.0187; // BB to BBB;  BB to BB;   BB to B
p[6][5] = 0.0010; p[6][6] = 0.9751; p[6][7] = 0.0239; // B to BB;    B to B;     B to CCC;
p[7][6] = 0.0066; p[7][7] = 0.9852; p[7][8] = 0.0082; // CCC to B;   CCC to CCC; CCC to D
p[8][8] = 1.0;                                        // D to D
```

I understand roughly that I need to use a uniform from 0 to 1 to see if the credit rating falls and then check if that is a new low. I understand that might including using some sort of vector. I would compute the value over a bunch of simulations and then divide it by the number of simulations then divide it by 120 months.

I need to create a Monte Carlo simulation to estimate the monthly premium that I should pay for this arrangement.

You can only receive money for a NEW low, and the bond rating begins at an A. There is assumed independence between months. Since there are only 5 possible "new lows", the arrangement is essentially an insurance policy that can pay out a maximum of \$100 million. Though I do need to use a simulation, I am open to a numerical solution that would further my understanding.

Comment: Could you please explain what these probabilities represent and precisely how they provide information about "dropping to a new low during the ten years"?  Why is what you pay per month of any relevance to the question? To what quantity does your "uniform" refer?

Comment: The probabilities are the likelihood the bond rating changes during that month. So P[1][2] is the likelihood that a AAA becomes AA. When I say uniform, I mean that what I was thinking of doing was generating a uniform random number between 0 and 1 and seeing if that number is less than P[i][i] and changing the bond rating accordingly.

Comment: It is important to edit the question itself so it reflects such essential information.  You also need to state what the starting rating is; what assumptions you are making about independence (or lack thereof) between months; and what you mean by the payoff.  For instance, if the credit rating falls successively from AAA through D, it will have attained seven new lows: does that mean you receive \$140 million or just \$20 million?

Comment: The credit rating begins at an A (can't believe I was stupid enough to forget that). I believe it is assumed to be independent. And you cannot fall multiple credit ratings during 1 month. If I go from A to B to A to B to C. I only receive $20 million because I only receive money for a NEW low.

Comment: It's getting clearer, but something is still vague: you talk about a 10 year horizon.  What is the payoff if during that period there are multiple new lows?

Comment: Every month you pay me x dollar. The first payment is today and payments continue for 10 years (120 payments) or until the underlying entity defaults, which ever comes first. Any month over the next 10 years in which the entity’s credit rating changes downward to a new low I pay you $20 million.

Comment: Thanks--that information needs to appear in the question itself.  Incidentally, I believe a relatively simple calculation will solve this problem; no simulation is necessary. You might want to indicate whether you are open to such direct solutions of whether, for some reason, you really must perform a simulation.

Comment: I further edited the problem. Unfortunately, a simulation is necessary, but I don't understand how I would solve this problem numerically either. And the qualm of the program is how I would write a "new low" into a while loop type situation.

Comment: Your comments next to the code don't quite match up to the probabilities. For instance, you seem to be using the indexes 0 and 1 *both* for AAA bonds.

Comment: (Assuming I did the calculations correctly) an accurate simulation should come close to \$255,182.13.

Comment: How does a credit default swap even factor into a premium calculation? It must make your premiums higher, obviously, since it's essentially an insurance plan.